# Why would IE NOT throw a mixed content security warning in this scenario?

Tags: html, css, security, internet-explorer

So I have a strange situation. I have a web page that SHOULD throw a mixed content warning popup in Internet Explorer, but doesn't always do it. Basically, on my https:// page, there's a CSS file that references an icon located at an http:// absolute URL and uses it as the background-image of a .

My main test machine for IE compatibility is using IE 9, and I have an IE 8 virtual machine.

On IE 9, I can clear the cache and refresh the page, and in Fiddler, I see the browser go out and request the icon as the page loads, and there's no security warning. The icon just shows up like all of the other resources.

On IE 8, if I clear the cache and hit the same page, I get the expected security warning ("Do you want to only load the secure content") and the loading behavior works as expected (clicking "Yes" will not load the icon, clicking "No" will load it).

I'm trying to determine why IE 9 isn't throwing that error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE9 [does not block or ask about "unsecure images"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/06/23/internet-explorer-9-security-part-4-protecting-consumers-from-malicious-mixed-content.aspx) any longer by default

> If a HTTPS page contains unsecure images, the images are permitted by default. We did this to provide a friendlier user-experience given how frequently Web sites make this mistake with images.

This is on par with some other browsers. E.g. Firefox classifies images as "passive content" and [does not block them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent) either.